# Pybossa: Increasing number of taskruns in API

Tags: pybossa

As per [this](http://docs.pybossa.com/en/latest/api.html) link of the documentation, we can limit the task runs to max of 100.

> By default PYBOSSA limits the list of items to 20. If you want to get
>   more items, use the keyword limit=N with N being a number to get that
>   amount. There is a maximum of 100 to the limit keyword, so if you try
>   to get more items at once it won’t work.

But, I need to increase the limit further to 200. How can I do this?